# If $a^2+b^2 = c^2$ and $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle, can we say the triangle is a right triangle?

Tags: geometry

This may in fact be a silly question.

Pythagoras tells us that $a,b,c$ are sides of a right triangle, then $a^2+b^2=c^2$. But is the converse true, that is if $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle such that $a^2+b^2 = c^2$ then can we conclude the triangle is a right triangle?

Comment: Yes.  It follows from the law of cosines.

Comment: Oh yes, $c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$ we must have $\cos\theta = 0$ that is $\theta = \pi/2$

Comment: Yes, the Pythagorean theorem is an "if and only if" proposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two triangles. One is a right triangle with legs of length $a$ and $b$. The second triangle has sides $a$, $b$, and $c$ for which $a^2+b^2=c^2$. In the first triangle, by the forward direction of the proof, hypotenuse $x$ satisfies $x^2=a^2+b^2$. Since $a^2+b^2=c^2$, it must be the case that $x^2=c^2$, and this implies that $x=c$. Hence, two triangles have equal sides and are therefore congruent. Consequently, corresponding angles are equal. It follows that the angle opposite side $c$ in the second triangle must be a right angle.

Comment: This is a great proof! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You read that *very* quickly, but I am glad it helped. `:-)`

Comment: Someone briefly posted (commented) a link to another site where there is a proof that is similar, hence the speed!